# How can the physical RAM size be determined in Linux programatically?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

On the command line this can be found out using the 'free' utility and 'cat /proc/meminfo'.
What would be the different ways to find out the physical RAM size in Linux programatically from a :

1. Userspace Application
2. Kernel Module

What API calls are available ?

Comment: If its a duplicate, please point out to a similar question and then this can be closed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>

long long physical_mem_bytes = (long long) sysconf (_SC_PHYS_PAGES) * sysconf (_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

Other than the command line ulimit, I don't know of a way of finding maximum memory for an individual process.

Comment: I am not looking for the memory size of a particular process, rather the entire Physical RAM.

Comment: Note, this may overflow if compiled to a 32 arch and executed on a 64 bit machine, which may have more than 2^32 bytes. Happened to me. Better cast both values to uint64_t or long long.

Comment: "Other than the command line ulimit..." -> If ulimit can show the info, the ulimit source code will revel how we can get those numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically, Linux won't tell you the actual physical size. Instead you should read this info from SMBIOS with, e.g.,

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | fgrep -ie 'size:'
```

This will give you results like the following (from a box with 4 RAM banks, only 2 installed):

```
Maximum Memory Module Size: 16384 MB
Maximum Total Memory Size: 65536 MB
Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
Installed Size: Not Installed
Enabled Size: Not Installed
Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
Installed Size: Not Installed
Enabled Size: Not Installed
Size: 2048 MB
Size: No Module Installed
Size: 2048 MB
Size: No Module Installed
```

Add the reported sizes (or `Enabled Size`s, but some BIOSes empirically don't report that) to get (in this case) 4096 MB. (Extra points for code that automates the parsing and arithmetic, but you can probably do that in your head nearly as reliably.)

To check your computation, run

```
fgrep -e 'MemTotal:' /proc/meminfo
```

The value reported by `/proc/meminfo` should not be more than the value you compute from `dmidecode`. In this case, empirically I get

```
MemTotal:        3988616 kB
```

Comment: That's a more literal interpretation of the question than I think was intended.  It's true that the kernel's visible/usable memory and the amount of physical DRAM on the machine chassis are not required to be the same.  But in almost all cases it's the former number that a programmer is interested in.

Comment: From emperical evidence calls to sysconf will give you values such as 2037mb. Using SMBIOS you will get the right answer, such as 2048mb, guaranteed. Further, you can share the code among userspace and kernel code, the parsing is the same.

Comment: But as I pointed out, the kernel may or may not be using that physical memory, even if it is on the board and exposed by the firmware.  The proper answer to the question "how much DRAM is available" it to check /proc/meminfo.  Your answer is correct only if you are asking a question about hardware configuraiton and not software tuning.  My understanding of the context of the question is that is not the case.

Comment: I think Jared's answer makes sense. It does give the exact value. Just that an API call is perhaps not available.

Answer (score -1):

`cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: you just took that from the question :-p

Comment: Yeh, too little coffee in the morning. But what's wrong with reading and parsing /proc/meminfo from an application?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  Reading and parsing from the /proc filesystem is a well-established programmatic interface to the Linux kernel.

Answer (score -1):

specifically from memory, I got this result from what Jared said
`sudo dmidecode -t memory`
there you can read the specs for each individual memory slot, so you will read something like 2048MB, in my case I have 2 of these being 4gb, despite my non PAE kernel only shows about 3.3gb and all other applications wont say the real physical memory, only dmidecode, thx!

Comment: That's a long sentence! Can you take your time to format next time you write an answer?  Thanks